# How can I create 5-min time step file names in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have start and end time

```
startTime = 12-Jun-2011 00:00:00
endTime = 13-Jun-2011 1:45:00
```

And I want to create filenames every five minutes of this sort to store in an array:

```
RATE.20110612.000000.tif
RATE.20110612.000500.tif
RATE.20110612.001000.tif
RATE.20110612.001500.tif
.
.
.
RATE.20110613.014000.tif
RATE.20110613.014500.tif
```

So far I am doing this:

```
endTime = datenum('13-Jun-2011 1:45:00');
startTime = datenum('12-Jun-2011 00:00:00');
minSteps =int8(((endTime-startTime)*24*60)/5) %Number of 5 minute steps between start and end time

for k = 1:minSteps
   FileNames{k} = strcat('RATE.',datestr(startTime, 'yyyymmdd.hhMMss'), '.tif');
   startTime = addtodate(startTime, 5, 'minute');
end
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do it? The number of steps computation is also wrong.

Comment: In your last piece of code, `startTime` and `endTime` seem to have switched. Is this the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: The [maximum value of an `int8` is 127](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int8.html?refresh=true). Your calculated number of intervals is 309.

Comment: These int8 values are a pain to work with. I primarily work in R and didn't encounter these issues before...Please suggest how I can fix it...

Comment: @mikkola Which line are you referring to?

Comment: You fix it by using a different class (`int16`, `int32`, `int64`) or by not casting it as an integer at all, use `ceil` or `floor`. Unless you have a specific reason to recast your value as an integer there really isn't any need here.

Comment: @maximusdooku The very first two lines defining the variables; in the non-working example you post.

Comment: @mikkola That was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The int64 fixed the problem. Rest of the code was fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for `int8`:

> Values range from –2<sup>7</sup> to 2<sup>7</sup> – 1.

This gives a maximum value of `127`.

From your example, your maximum value is `309`:

```
startTime = datenum('12-Jun-2011 00:00:00');
endTime = datenum('13-Jun-2011 1:45:00');
minSteps = ((endTime-startTime)*24*60)/5

minSteps =

  309.0000
```

So attempting to recast `minSteps` to `int8` is going to return the maximum value, `127`.

Either recast to an integer class with a higher limit ([`int16`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int16.html), [`int32`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int32.html), [`int64`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int64.html), [`uint16`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint16.html), [`uint32`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint32.html), [`uint64`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint64.html)) or don't bother recasting to an integer at all and just round `minSteps` ([`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html), [`ceil`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html), [`round`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html)). Unless you have a specific need to have `minSteps` as an integer, there's really no point in recasting it, it's not going to affect the values of `k` in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Why not avoid the `for` loop and the calculations by using `duration` objects and create a vector of `datetime`(s) ?

```
startTime = datetime('12-Jun-2011 00:00:00');
endTime = datetime('13-Jun-2011 1:45:00');
dt = duration(0,5,0); % 5 min interval

% Get vector of datetime values in the interval
timeVec = startTime:dt:endTime;

% print datetime values in required format
fileIds = cellstr(datestr(timeVec,'yyyymmdd.HHMMSS')); 
fileNames = strcat(repmat({'RATE.'},numel(fileIds),1),fileIds,repmat({'.tif'},numel(fileIds),1));

>> fileNames

fileNames = 

'RATE.20110612.000000.tif'
'RATE.20110612.000500.tif'
'RATE.20110612.001000.tif'
'RATE.20110612.001500.tif'
....
'RATE.20110613.013500.tif'
'RATE.20110613.014000.tif'
'RATE.20110613.014500.tif'
```

Comment: Note that this requires R2014b or newer